# Migrated site - Images have 404 error

Tags: images, htaccess, 404-error

I migrated my site from localhost (LAMP) to Namecheap and it is broken in that the images it is supposed to load from `/wp-content` return a 404 error.

I can login to wp-admin and I can see the pages which load menus and text correctly. But I can't seem to get the images to load, I have tried:

- flushing permalinks
- some `.htaccess` and wp-config changes

For example: The logo does not load when you're on the `/about` page:

```
https://example.com/site_dir/about
```

If you go to the wp-content folder the image is there but the site is not looking for it in the right directory (wp-content is in a subdirectory):

```
https://example.com/site_dir/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/site_dir_logo_light_textfull.png
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: i can recommend [this](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB) tool. be carefull to read the manual on how it exactly works, since it will manipulate your database and overwrite some contents..

Comment: "not looking for it in the right directory" - Specifically, your site is looking for the image in the document root. ie. the URL is formatted: `/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/entiere_logo_light_textfull.png`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your localhost site had WordPress installed in the root directory but your production site is in a sub-directory.

You should review the instructions in the the WordPress Codex for [Moving WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) to see if you missed any steps. It describes both moving a WordPress installation from one server to another, and moving it from one directory to another. It seems like you did both, so all those instructions would apply.

Answer (score 0):

So @juggler and @mrwhite were both correct.

Following the instructions to move wordpress into a subfolder would have worked. The problem had to do with the fact that I set up virtual hosts on my localhost machine, because I had multiple wordpress installs in the /var/www/html directory.

So I installed the migrated site in the root folder and it now works. I also had to enable mod_c rewrite rules for apache so that it would show write correctly to my .htaccess file. And I had to edit the site sitename and URL in the database wp-options table.